# Python - sending unicode characters (prefixed with \u) in an HTTP POST request

Tags: python, unicode

I'm writing a program which fetches and edits articles on Wikipedia, and I'm having a bit of trouble handling Unicode characters prefixed with \u. I've tried .encode("utf8") and it isn't seeming to do the trick here. How can I properly encode these values prefixed with \u to POST to Wikipedia? See [this edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=100_Bullets&diff=prev&oldid=532920346) for my problem.
Here is some code:
To get the page:

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles="+urllib.quote(name)+"&prop=revisions&rvprop=content"
articleContent = ClientCookie.urlopen(url).read().split('"*":"')[1].split('"}')[0].replace("\\n", "\n").decode("utf-8")
```

Before I POST the page:

```
data = dict([(key, value.encode('utf8')) for key, value in data.iteritems()])
data["text"] = data["text"].replace("\\", "")
editInfo = urllib2.Request("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", urllib.urlencode(data))
```

Comment: We'd love to see some code.

Comment: I'll add some in a second.

Comment: I'd love to see some example data; you posted `u2013` as literal text (5 characters), it doesn't look like you had a `\u2013` codepoint (*one* character) in the first place.

Comment: I did, just .replace("\\", "") changed it.

Comment: The entire code is at http://pastebin.com/9QMqUeEX

Comment: `data["text"].replace("\\u", "\u")` is not going to make things work..

Comment: I see that now... what can I do to fix this? I have a feeling it is Tkinter Text widget doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are downloading JSON data without decoding it. Use the [`json` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for that:

```
import json

articleContent = ClientCookie.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(articleContent)
```

JSON encoded data looks a lot like Python, it uses `\u` escaping as well, but it is in fact a subset of JavaScript.

The `data` variable now holds a deep datastructure. Judging by the string splitting, you wanted this piece:

```
articleContent = data['query']['pages'].values()[0]['revisions'][0]['*']
```

*Now* articleContent is an actual `unicode()` instance; it is the revision text of the page you were looking for:

```
>>> print u'\n'.join(data['query']['pages'].values()[0]['revisions'][0]['*'].splitlines()[:20])
{{For|the game|100 Bullets (video game)}}
{{GOCEeffort}}
{{italic title}}
{{Supercbbox  <!--Wikipedia:WikiProject Comics-->
| title =100 Bullets
| image =100Bullets vol1.jpg
| caption = Cover to ''100 Bullets'' vol. 1 "First Shot, Last Call". Cover art by Dave Johnson.
| schedule = Monthly
| format =
|complete=y
|Crime       = y
| publisher = [[Vertigo (DC Comics)|Vertigo]]
| date = August [[1999 in comics|1999]] – April [[2009 in comics|2009]]
| issues = 100
| main_char_team = [[Agent Graves]] <br/> [[Mr. Shepherd]] <br/> The Minutemen <br/> [[List of characters in 100 Bullets#Dizzy Cordova (also known as "The Girl")|Dizzy Cordova]] <br/> [[List of characters in 100 Bullets#Loop Hughes (also known as "The Boy")|Loop Hughes]]
| writers = [[Brian Azzarello]]
| artists = [[Eduardo Risso]]<br>Dave Johnson
| pencillers =
| inkers =
| colorists = Grant Goleash<br>[[Patricia Mulvihill]]
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked and the unicode characters properly display in the textbox.